# Can packages.config be hidden in Solution Explorer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore, solution-explorer

I like NuGet, and I like how it so kindly restores my packages.  However, I'm pretty tired of the packages.config file showing up in the alphabetical listing of my classes in the project root like this:

[image: Oh, packages.config! Why must you be here?]

I seem to recall that excluding the file from the project (but leaving it on disk and in source control) will break the ability to restore packages.  Is there anything that can be done to bring beauty to the project root?

Comment: Do you think, it is better to have a file that is mapped to source control but not visible in project?

Comment: @T.S. - I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, or, at least, whether or not it's rhetorical.  Personally, I have no problem excluding vital files from a project, but leaving them on disk and in source control.  I find this method works well for things that aren't typically modified in the text editor, but need to be in place for other reasons.  Some examples that come to mind are ReSharper's "DotSettings" files, and the JS files that TypeScript transpiles.

Comment: Resharper settings are not part of your project setup, but your nuget is. Especially if you keep restoring those packages. If scale of operation is large, you can't afford this. You download package once, check-in DLLs and never restore it again. If you have 300 projects and you need to unify nuget version, same thing. You can't afford keep restoring.  In this sense I don't even need packages.config altogether

Comment: @T.S. - It's still not very clear to me, the point you're trying to make.  I don't and won't check NuGet packages themselves into source control. The packages.config files are ones I never edit. They're only there, in my case, so NuGet's GUI can restore packages when needed. This is true with 3 or 300 projects. It works swimmingly. I just don't need to see that config file among my classes in Solution Explorer. As per the accepted answer, I excluded them from the projects, but they're still in source control and still seem to do their job in terms of NuGet package restoration. Is this bad?

Comment: It is not bad. I just don't see reason to download same package over and over again when you clear out your branch. We just check in DLLs and they are always there

Comment: Oh, so you're not concerned with hiding the packages.config. You just don't want to use package restore? That's fine. There's plenty of literature out there about why you shouldn't check packages into source control, but ultimately it's up to a given team. I avoid checking packages into source control, but that's not really what this question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project should restore the packages that installed based on the packages.config file no matter it include in project or not. So You can exclude it.

Comment: Oh.  Then I suppose I stand corrected!  I'll mark this as the answer, and on the off chance that removing the files from the project does lead to something undesired, I'll revisit this.